# Why is the SQLite provider missing from the Server Explorer Add Connection dialogue?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, sqlite, system.data.sqlite

I am following the article [Using SQLite Embedded Database with Entity Framework and Linq-to-SQL](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/236918/Using-SQLite-embedded-database-with-entity-framewo), and have tried installing the SQLite provider, first using the System.Data.SQLite  NuGet package, and then by installing the provider via the [Setups for 32-bit Windows (.NET /Framework 4.0)](http://system.data.sqlite.org/index.html/doc/trunk/www/downloads.wiki) installer package (for v1.0.79). After both installs, and a system restart, I still see no *SQLite Database File* provider in the *Add Connection* dialogue from Server Explorer.

I can proceed by manually creating a connection string and using external tools to create my SQLite database file, but I still would like to know what is wrong why I do not have the advertised design time support for SQLite despite having installed the latest provider. What could be wrong here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ensure the data tools for visual studio were installed correctly as per:

http://www.basarat.com/2010/05/sqlite-for-visual-studio-2010.html

There are various fixes listed, making sure there weren't older tools installed first, etc. 
I'm going to give it a try, but the article may help you out.

Comment: You mean in the comments section, right? The main blog entry hardly says anything at all. I have come right with this, but am leaving the question open in the hope of not having the bounty expire and be automatically awarded. I reinstalled and ensured I checked the 'install assemblies to GAC' option. That seems to have worked, hope it helps you as well.

Comment: Ya in the comments section. Reinstall was one of the recommendations.