# Why is the SQLite provider missing from the Server Explorer Add Connection dialogue in VS 11?

Tags: sqlite, system.data.sqlite, visual-studio-2012, server-explorer

My challenge is exactly as described here: [Why is the SQLite provider missing from the Server Explorer Add Connection dialogue?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9341114/why-is-the-sqlite-provider-missing-from-the-server-explorer-add-connection-dialo) albeit mine is for VS 11 Beta. An excerpt is as follows:

"I am following the article Using SQLite Embedded Database with Entity Framework and Linq-to-SQL, and have tried installing the SQLite provider, first using the System.Data.SQLite NuGet package, and then by installing the provider via the Setups for 32-bit Windows (.NET /Framework 4.0) installer package (for v1.0.79). After both installs, and a system restart, I still see no SQLite Database File provider in the Add Connection dialogue from Server Explorer.

I can proceed by manually creating a connection string and using external tools to create my SQLite database file, but I still would like to know what is wrong why I do not have the advertised design time support for SQLite despite having installed the latest provider. What could be wrong here?"

Please can anybody help with VS11 SQL Lite Integration?

Comment: One way is to download source code change the manifest and installer and install it locally.